# Spark, databricks, save to CSV no columns name

Tags: csv, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am using Spark databricks csv to save the dataframe to csv. However, I cannot get the CSV file with the columns. It is Plain text.

Please check the code below:

```
  df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("head", "true").save("~/Desktop/JSON/abc_name.csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper option is "header", not "head". Please see the [docs](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#scala-api)

`df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("~/Desktop/JSON/abc_name.csv")`

Comment: Thanks. It works. And, I also remove the JSON column in dataFrame.